# What's the difference between "Storyboard ID" and "Use Storyboard ID" in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I always only use **Storyboard ID** and never use the checkbox **Use Storyboard ID** so wondering when it is required to use the checkbox.

These options are located in the **Identity Inspector** at xcode

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Restoration Identifier** is used to restore state of your View Controller.

If we want to implement app state restoration in our app, we must use restoration identifiers for the view controllers that we want to be restored.

General rule for setting the restoration identifier is to use the string of the **Storyboard Identifier**. We can use a totally different meaningful string for Restoration ID if we want. However, it is always neat to just use same name that Storyboard uses.

Checking the **Use Storyboard Identifier** on just copies the string from Storyboard Identifier to it and uses it.

Answer (score 10):

**Use Storyboard ID** will reuse the **Storyboard ID** as the **Restoration ID** for the Scene.

See how when you check **Use Storyboard ID** it prepopulates the **RestorationID**?

[image]

Comment: On Xcode 9.2 this is not happening. Is there a reason why it does not show as the image above?